# Why does quantum entanglement not allow us to send information faster than the speed of light?

Tags: quantum-entanglement

She said it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-aGIvUomTA

A lot of large newspapers claim that we will have internet faster than the speedof light. But she says it is wrong. I don't get it.

I thought that quantum entanglement would mean, that all you do with one particle will happen to the other particle at the very same moment without any time delay? Or does the affects take time?

Comment: Who is “she”? Questions are supposed to be self-contained and not require watching YouTube videos.

Comment: *A lot of large newspapers claim…* Please give an example of one such large newspaper.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer simply: if two particles $A$ and $B$ are entangled, if somone measures the particle A, it will have an instantaneous effect on $B$.

But the state of the particle $B$ will not end up in something you can control. It will be random. Thus you cannot use it to transfer information even though the effect is in a way instantaneous.

Comment: There is no instantaneous effect.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch it is instantaneous in the sense that the collapse of the wavefunction will be. Now I agree this is related to one interpretation of Q.M. But even more simply: no matter how far $A$ and $B$ are, their measurement outcomes will be correlated. In this sense there is some instantaneous effect because independent of the distance between them.